# Java - Listeners/Observers VS Subclass Protected Methods

Tags: java, methods, listener, protected, threadpoolexecutor

I observed in ThreadPoolExecutor below empty methods:

[`protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { }`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable))

[`protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { }`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable))

[`protected void terminated() { }`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#terminated())

in docs, it says that we can override those methods in subclasses or anonymous inner classes which will be invoked prior the process, this means those protected methods are representing listeners/observers to notify about next process in the pool.

My question is:

**What are the cons in the normal [listeners/observers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) which motivates Doug Lea to use this way?**

Comment: I suppose Doug is the person to ask if they made the decision; anyone else would probably just be making educated speculations.

Comment: I believe documentation of those methods is pretty clear. Can you please explain which part you don't understand. And how you think it is related to listeners/observers?

Comment: @AmitBera re-read the question

Answer (score 1):

Making a listener for these three events would be a superior approach if you wanted to make access to these events public, because it provides a much higher degree of decoupling between the class and its listeners.

Making the access protected implies a higher degree of affinity between the class and the listener: the designers of the class would end up making a protected `RunnerListener` interface for the listener, adding a protected `DefaultRunnerListener` implementation for situations when you need to override one or two methods, and adding a protected method for you to supply the listener. Because access to such listener would be protected as well, you wouldn't be able to use a factory method for it.

Taking all this into account, the authors decided that it would be easier to supply protected methods, rather than adding the complexity above for decoupling that is not necessary.